# Not able to save multiple values in a column of SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, webforms

I have a drop down in form that allow users to select multiple value at the same time in R Shiny and saving the record in SQLite DB at the back end and data type is VARCHAR

[image]

dropDown:

[image]

But when i click on save button i am getting below error:

```
Error in : Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you all you need to know.  Your `selectInput` is returning a vector of `character`s.  Your database is expecting a scalar `character`.  So, either turn the value of the `selectInput` into a scalar (by concatenation or pasting) or modify your database so that it can accept multiple rows of data which correspond to your input.  The choice is yours.

I can't tell you which is more appropriate because you've provided no context.